# How to update DB when field changed in mongoalchemy.(flask)？

Tags: mongodb, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, pymongo, mongoalchemy

I am using flask-mongoalchemy to do a demo, and here is a question confused me for a while.
At first I create a class User

```
class Student(db.Document):
    '''student info'''
    name = db.StringField()
    grade = db.IntField(required=False, default=None)
```

Then, I use this DB and create some example, such as student1, student2...and so on。
Now, I change the default value of grade from None to 0

```
grade = db.IntField(required=False, default=0)
```

When I run query again, it raise error:

```
mongoalchemy.exceptions.BadValueException: Bad value for field of type "grade".  Reason: "Value is not an instance of <class 'int'>
```

SO， how to auto-update this field change?  What I did now is to modify the value of age in database manualy.

Comment: Can you drop `student` collection manually and build again? Or run update query in the mongo shell to set grade=0

Comment: @Valijon Can update operation change the table default value?

Comment: It can change if table meets requirements. In your case, perhaps once you create your `student` collection, MongoDB creates [$jsonSchema](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/) for validation. Check it: `db.getCollectionInfos({name: "student"})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to get the queries working as before set [`allow_none` option](https://github.com/dayorbyte/MongoAlchemy/blob/v0.7/mongoalchemy/fields.py#L130) on the field to `True`.

```
grade = db.IntField(required=False, default=0, allow_none=True)
```

That should allow documents having no value for grades to not trigger errors when unwrapped as python objects.

Next, make a migration that sets the default value for documents where grade is None to 0.

```py
from mongoalchemy.session import Session

with Session.connect('mongoalchemy') as s:
    update = s.query(Student).filter(Student.grade == None).set(User.grade, 0)
    update.execute()
```

Lastly, switch the field declaration back to disallow `None` values for the grade.